# Struts2 How to dynamically apply a comparator to a given List

Tags: struts2

Is it possible to apply one of the comparators on a List based on a drop down selection?

For example, I have two comparators defined:

```
<s:bean name="comparator.CreateDateComparator" var="createDateComparator"/>
<s:bean name="comparator.LastUpdatedDateComparator" var="lastDateComparator"/>
```

Based on a certain selected value from a dropdown, I would like use the right comparator for my sorting. Something like this:

```
<s:if test="dropDownValue=='CREATE_DATE'" >
<s:sort comparator="createDateComparator" source="dataList">
```

Comment: If you're already making a round-trip to the server, why not just sort on the server side? What's gained by doing this in the view layer?

Comment: Thanks Dave. Just wanted to explore whether comparators could be changed on the View or not. I would probably not gain much as you suggested since the sorting is already being done at the server side.